# Why do my grouped material nodes not appear as a box?

Tags: node-editor, groups

In [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=393zz7KDa_c), when the user groups some material nodes (at around 8m25s), they appear as a box which he can rename.

When I follow this step, my whole node background goes a shade of green.  The only way I can get out of this is to hit tab or edit group to go up and down the node hierarchy.

Why can't I see my group of nodes boxed like in the tutorial?

my screen
[image: my screen]

tutorial screen
[image: their screen]

Comment: That is not a node group, that is a Frame Node

Comment: Ah! Makes sense now!  He said J but I assumed it was a group!  Please add as an answer!